# FOR XML low performance in query plan using TYPE

Tags: xml, performance, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate text from a table using FOR XML PATH.
Using this:

```
SELECT (
SELECT ',' + MyColumn
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH, TYPE
).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

I get what I want (because I need the special characters not encoded)
But checking the Query plan I get a not desired number, so comparing vs the same query just removing the part of type I am getting a better number in the query plan.
This is the query which I compared

```
SELECT (
SELECT ',' + MyColumn
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH(''))
```

I am talking of a table with 400k rows and I am using a subquery, but I wanted to put a simple example of code just to simplify that the issue is with the TYPE section of the FOR XML, I get this numbers:

For first:

[image]

For second I get:

[image]

What is the reason of this?

I cannot only use the second because that way encode the special characters, and I don't need that.
Is there any workaround in order to let a good performance (marked in query plan)?

Comment: I hazard a guess that it is `nvarchar(max)` that is killing you. Can you use a smaller width?

Comment: I changed the NVARCHAR(MAX) with a value and I get the same number in query plan. Seems like is not affecting.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much you can do... Your queries are pretty straight... Calling this with `(SELECT .. FOR XML ..., TYPE),value(...)` is the appropriate way if your strings might include special characters... Which special characters are there? It could be a workaround to call this without `TYPE and .value()`, but do a manual `REPLACE` yourself... Are you really concatenating 400k values with a comma?

Comment: You are showing the estimated numbers, but did you actually time your query execution?